# How do you interpret the numbers in square?

Tags: classical-guitar

I am puzzled by the number put in the square in the sheet music. Can anyone tell me how to play?

[image]

Comment: Interesting, also the upside down T marks. I would expect them to be explained in the book. They are not part of standard notation. They seem to indicate the bass string on which the _next_ note will be played, so perhaps it's some guideline for fingering.

Comment: Thanks for your response! The arranger writes “I used unconventional notation. I hope  you understand what I have in mind” 

Comment: Some upside down T's have a 4, 5, or 6.  Some have nothing at all.  Their vertical position isn't consistently aligned with staff lines or staff spaces or noteheads.  Does a pattern emerge eventually?  What is the arranger's full name -- does googling that find any hints?

Answer (score 1):

At each point a Barre is recommended and the number in the square box is the number of strings it should cover. I would need to see a few more pages to be absolutely sure.